# Which is the official organization for domain registration?

Tags: domain

Is there an official organization for domain registration?

I've seen many sites that provide this service.

http://www.name.com/
http://www.godaddy.com
http://www.register.com/
and so on...

Comment: Does "orgon" stand for "organization"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited.

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic, but the question is answered and done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Name.com, Go Daddy and Register.com are [domain name registrars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar), of which there are many and all of whom have the authority to register a domain name on your behalf.

The [Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICANN) (ICANN) is the authority from which the registrars get their ability. ICANN helps maintain the top level domains like .com, .net, .uk, etc.